Does the ptr function in opencv convert values to the desired type?
I have been browsing the opencv source code for unrelated reasons, and could not find the documentation that explains what exactly happens in this line:
const double* const distPtr = distCoeffs.ptr<double>();
double k1 = distPtr[0];
double k2 = distPtr[1];

The variable distCoeffs originates from a getMat() call on a parameter of type InputArray. To my understanding, the InputArray does not guarantee that it contains doubles. It might as well be e.g. a float.
Right as I finished typing this question I realized that in my linked example, there is a conversion to ensure we don't hit this case:
if( !distCoeffs.empty() )
    distCoeffs = Mat_<double>(distCoeffs);

I still would like to know, generally, whether such a safeguard is necessary. I could not find the documentation for cv::Mat::ptr except for a redirect to the docs for isContinuous, which does not explicitly answer my question.
Does the distCoeffs.ptr<double>(); expect the values to be doubles and will otherwise misbehave? Or is this a safe conversion even if the input parameter was actually e.g. an std::vector<float>?

same goes for the at<>() method: NO it doesn't, and that isn't its purpose. it's ancient API, from sometime around 2009, made to adapt to even older API that was C.

Looking at the source code in their repo (https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp):
template<typename _Tp> inline
_Tp* Mat::ptr(int y)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) );
    return (_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * y);
}

So the assumption is implicit: a C-style cast of the underlying pointer, most likely a reinterpret-cast.
Using this pointer to dereference data that is wrongly converted could be UB, depending on the types involved.  If not, it would most likely be junk.  For example, if the mat holds floats, reinterpret-cast to double would just append the byte data of two floats together and read them as a single double, which would be a garbage value.
Another potential issue if the template type is wider, is that you may try to dereference data at an index beyond the buffer, thinking that the index exist (remember that the buffer size in bytes doesn't change, but would be divided among larger elements.)
Edit: added an example and the second issue

The ptr(int i0) method:

Returns a pointer to the specified matrix row.

Assuming the row index you supplied is valid, it will always give you a correct address to the beginning of the row, regardless of whether the type you supplied as the template agrument is the correct one.
This is because the implementation is using the step property (AKA stride) which is always the actual correct "jump" between rows:
template<typename _Tp> inline
_Tp* Mat::ptr(int y)
{
    CV_DbgAssert( y == 0 || (data && dims >= 1 && (unsigned)y < (unsigned)size.p[0]) );
    return (_Tp*)(data + step.p[0] * y);
}

The issue of the element type that you supply arises only when you actually use it.
The method ptr itself only casts the data address to the type you supplied, but if it's the wrong type you will end up with UB (undefined-behavior) when you attempt to derefernce it.
Bottom line:

Does the ptr function in opencv convert values to the desired type?

No it doesn't. As mentioned above it will only cast the address of the data row to a pointer to the type you specified.
A side note:
The ptr method does have an assert check (for debug only) that the row index you supplied is valid.
